# How to squash commits in a branch and rebase all it's descendant branches?

Tags: git, github

**Before**

```
master:  o--o
             \
branch1:      1--2--3
                     \
branch2:              4--5--6
```

**Desired after**

```
master:  o--o
             \
branch1:      1'
               \
branch2:        4'--5'--6'
```

This is my typical workflow where I work on a feature in branch2 that is dependent on feature in branch1. When branch1 is mature for a review I squash it into one single commit, and rebase branch2 to be based on the new squashed commit.

However after squashing branch1, the fork point between branch1 and branch2 is now the master HEAD. `git rebase` will attempt to rebase `{1..6}` onto `1'`.

I know I can manually tell git the fork point, but is there a way to pragmatically figure out the fork point in this case?

Answer (score 1):

One automatic way? You would go one of two ways:

- Tell git what the previous branch position was for the squashed branch:

`git rebase --onto squashed-branch old-non-squashed-branch-or-revision feature-branch`

- Telling git how many revisions your feature branch has. Say it has 5 revisions:

`git rebase --onto squashed-branch feature-branch~5 feature-branch`

Comment: This is not what I would call "automatic". I'm looking for some way for the branch to "remember" the previous branch position.

Comment: hahaha.... forgot to remove the "automatic" part.... an nope, branches don't remember anything... branches _in git_ are just pointers to revisions. You might leave a temp branch at the original position of the branch.