# How can I rebase a dependent branch on a squashed commit avoiding conflicts?

Tags: git, branch, rebase, squash

I have 3 branches

- feature `A` (not managed by me)
- feature `B` (managed by me)
- branch `main`

My `B` branch is dependant from the branch `A` and `A` is already squashed in the `main` branch.
This graph shows the curret situation.

[image: current git graph]

I want to move (rebase) `B` on the comment corresponding to `Squashed A`.
I used the command `git checkout B && git rebase main` to rebase it but I have a lot of conflicts to manage and is not so easy to avoid problems or bugs.

I have find out [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61349942/how-to-squash-commits-in-a-branch-and-rebase-all-its-descendant-branches) but I have an already squashed branch (not Squashed by me).
How can I have this result with few commands without having so much throubles with few ?

[image: expected result git graph]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question you linked actually contains the answer to your question:

```bash
# With start exclusive, end inclusive
# git rebase --onto <where> <current-start> <current-end>

# Presented in a specific way for your case:
# git rebase --onto <squashed-commit> <old-non-squashed-branch-or-revision> <feature-branch>

# That is:
git rebase --onto main A B
```

This should give you exact same content as `B` before the operations.

*You can double check by creating a tag before doing anything and using `git diff <tag-before-ops> B` after the operations.*

---

**Important:** as suggested by @eftshift0, this is assuming that `A` has not changed and still is in the state before squashing.

If that's not the case, you may use any ref pointing to the state of `A` before squashing like `B~2` in this very example or the commit hash directly.

Comment: I upvoted the answer, however, as a generalization, I would advice to be careful about using `A` in the example..... just in case the branch has moved (for whatever reason). So, `git rebase --onto main position-of-A-in-branch-B B` or also if `B` is not long and it's a straight line, you could use the number of commits in `B` after `A`... suppose it's 3 commits: `git rebase --onto main B~3 B`

Comment: Very good point @eftshift0, I updated my answer to highlight this.